# Error: =: command not found (Bash Script)

Tags: bash

I found a nifty little shell script that I wanted to use from [this website here.](https://coderwall.com/p/moabdw) I have followed everything step-by-step, but receive the following error when running this on my CentOS box.

```
./deploy: line 3: =: command not found
```

Line 3 only contains...

```
$ERRORSTRING = "Error. Please make sure you've indicated correct parameters"
```

I've tried toying around with a bit, but don't understand why it won't accept the "=" character. Is there something wrong with the script, or is it merely something different in the way that my server processes the script?

Comment: There are spaces around the `=` sign. Read the corresponding line as `$ERRORSTRING="Error. Please make sure you've indicated correct parameters"` with no spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: (1) Remove spaces around `=`.  (2) When assigning a variable, don't use `$` (on the LHS).

Comment: `ERRORSTRING="Error. Please make sure you've indicated correct parameters"`

Comment: Don't copy scripts from anywhere without verifying its effectiveness.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance -- I'm good to go now. :-) Devnull's answer was correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Devnulls" answer was correct -- I had to remove the spaces around the "=" and remove the "$" from that line as well. The end result was...

```
ERRORSTRING="Error. Please make sure you've indicated correct parameters"
```

I've upvoted Devnull and gniourf_gniourf's comments.

Thank you to all whom have assisted!

Answer (score 19):

Gah, that script is full of bad scripting practices (in addition to the outright error you're running into). Here's the outright error:

```
$ERRORSTRING = "Error. Please make sure you've indicated correct parameters"
```

As devnull pointed out, this should be:

```
ERRORSTRING="Error. Please make sure you've indicated correct parameters"
```

A couple of lines down (and again near the end), we have:

```
echo $ERRORSTRING;
```

...which *works*, but contains two bad ideas: a variable reference without double-quotes around it (which will sometimes be parsed in unexpected ways), and a semicolon at the end of the line (which is a sign that someone is trying to write C or Java or something in a shell script).  Use this instead:

```
echo "$ERRORSTRING"
```

The next line is:

```
elif [ $1 == "live" ]
```

...which *might* work, depending on whether the value of `$1` has spaces, or is defined-but-blank, or anything like that (again, use double-quotes to prevent misparsing!). Also, the == comparison operator is nonstandard -- it'll work, because bash supports it in its `[ ... ]` builtin syntax, but if you're counting on having bash extensions available, why not use the much cleaner `[[ ... ]]` replacement? Any of these would be a better replacement for that line:

```
elif [ "$1" = "live" ]
elif [[ $1 == "live" ]]
elif [[ "$1" == "live" ]]
```

Personally, I prefer the last. The double-quotes aren't needed in this particular case, but IMO it's safest to just double-quote all variable references unless there's a specific reason not to. A bit further down, there's a `elif [ $2 == "go" ]` that the same comments apply to.

BTW, there's a good sanity-checking tool for shell scripts at [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net). It's not quite as picky as I am (e.g. it doesn't flag semicolons at the ends of lines), but it pointed out all of the actual errors in this script...